# How many bottom layers for a DLP printer?

Tags: adhesion, dlp

I just got an Anycubic Photon 4k DLP printer, and am experimenting with the print parameters in Photon Workshop.

I noticed that the number of bottom layers (40 second exposure time) was defaulted to 6.
Experimenting to get better quality near the build plate, I reduced the bottom layer to 1. This resulted in the first layer adhering just as well as before, but the part de-laminated from the first layer. The default exposure time on the other layers is 2 seconds and that has been working well.

Physically I do not see why the part would de-laminate from a well-adhered layer 1, but not de-laminate at a layer 6? maybe 6 bottom layers is hard coded in the slicing software and it just skipped exposing them? Curious if anyone else has run into this or understands the epoxy exposure dynamics a bit better.